# AWS, OpsWorks and Chef dependencies: what's the cleanest solution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, vagrant, aws-opsworks, librarian

I've got a Chef project that, locally with Vagrant, works really nicely. I'm using `librarian-chef`, which means I can specify my dependencies in a `Cheffile` like this:

```
site 'http://community.opscode.com/api/v1'
cookbook 'jenkins'
```

When I then run `librarian-chef install`, it pulls down `jenkins` and all the cookbooks it depends on into a `cookbooks` directory.

There's also another directory, `site-cookbooks`, which is where I'm writing all of my own custom cookbooks and recipes.

In the `Vagrantfile`, you can then tell it to look at two different paths for cookbooks:

```
config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
  chef.cookbooks_path = ["cookbooks", "site-cookbooks"]
  # snip
end
```

This works perfectly when I run `vagrant up`. However, it doesn't seem to play nicely with AWS OpsWorks – as this requires all cookbooks to be at the top level of the Chef repository.

My question then, is: **what's the nicest way to use Chef with OpsWorks** without including all of the dependencies at the top level of my repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of recently, [OpsWorks supports Chef 11.10 and Berkshelf](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2014/03/aws-opsworks-now-supports-chef-1110.html), giving you a much nicer way of managing cookbook dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

OpsWorks doesn't play nice with a number of tools created for Chef. I tried using it not long after it came out and gave up on it (OpsWorks was using Chef 9 at the time).

I suggest you either move from OpsWorks to Enterprise Chef, or try the following:

**1. Create a separate repo for your cookbooks**

Keep all cookbooks in a separate repo. If you want it a part of a larger repository, you can include it as *git submodule*. Git submodules are generally a **bad** thing but cookbooks are a separate entity, that can live independently of the rest of your project, so it actually works quite well in this case.

To add a cookbooks repository inside another repo, use:

```
git submodule add git://github.com/my/cookbooks.git ./cookbooks
```

**2. Keep your cookbooks together with community cookbooks**

You can either clone the cookbooks into your repository, add them as submodules, or try using librarian-chef/Berkshelf to manage them. You could try using this method, it should work with librarian-chef: https://sethvargo.com/using-amazon-opsworks-with-berkshelf/